# ios: how to solve this memory leak warning

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, cgcolor

I got the following code line:

```
mainLayer.shadowColor = CGColorCreate( CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components );
```

When I run Product->Analyse in xcode it gives me the warning:

```
Potential leak of an object allocated on line 176
```

So that means that I do not free my CGColor. Therefore I thought a good solution would be the following:

```
CGColorRef shadowColor = CGColorCreate( CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components ); 
mainLayer.shadowColor = shadowColor;
CGColorRelease( shadowColor );
```

But I still get the same leak warning. How do I repair the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need also to release colorspace:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGColorRef shadowColor = CGColorCreate( colorspace, components ); 
mainLayer.shadowColor = shadowColor;
CGColorRelease( shadowColor );
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this:

```
CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
```

by any change returning an object you're responsible for deallocating? I thought I remembered there being a function like CGColorSpaceRelease().